# I am new to android studio, can anyone when i add a video in raw folder under res folder it shows file was loaded in wrong encoding "UTF-8"

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to the android studio, When I create a raw folder under the res folder and then I add a video it shows an error like the file was loaded in the wrong encoding utf-8. I have searched every question on stack overflow and everywhere on the internet still I didn't get any answers which I was expecting. please help.

Comment: It is unclear who shows an error and when.

Comment: Android studio shows the error (File was loaded in the wrong encoding utf-8)  when I try to add a video in the raw folder. Please help.

Comment: Hard to believe. One can put any file in raw. Why should the IDE matter?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1430kfE7w4qdCvYp-_rHEYC1xkCS3twyOMgTUr6Jsl-Y/edit?usp=sharing   here I have shared the link of a screenshot in which you can see the error.

Comment: For that link an active google account is needed.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ndnbwcF  can you tell me now about the error?

Comment: To view that image i have to agree with their cookie policy.